# How to download Dark table on Linux Mint, from source code

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I am wondering if someone can explain to me how to download programs such as Dark table, using Linux Mint and the source code. I have consulted many sites, but they are not all beginner friendly.

Thank you very much,

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Installing open source projects with the source code is nothing beginner friendly. Depending on the software you want to install you need at least basic knowledge of build systems (in case of darktable it's cmake).

A general approach is: Look on the website of the project or the git repo for instructions on how to install manually ( e.g.: darktable: https://www.darktable.org/install/ chapter 'Install from source').
Most likely at the end, it will provide the steps to compile it. First step is always to install the dependencies. After that downloading the provided archives or clone the repo and executing the build commands or the provided build script. Then you most likley will have compiled an executable which you can execute or create a desktop entry for it on your mint desktop.